# How to get N rows after the first row matching a condition?

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I am implementing a cursor based pagination.

The requirement is to sort a dataset by an arbitrary condition (e.g. description) and return `N` rows after `X` row (where `X` represents the last item on the last page).

The first page is simple:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM probe
ORDER BY description ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Assuming this query returns IDs `4, 5, 2, 1, 3`, then the next query must produce 5 next results from the same query after `id` 3.

Note: We cannot use `LIMIT ... OFFSET` after the first page because the offset is relative to the position of the referenced result that we do not know.

The only way I can think of solving this problem is:

Find row number in the dataset for ID 3:

```
WITH
  data_index AS (
    SELECT
      d1.*,
      row_number() OVER () row_number
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM probe
      ORDER BY description ASC
    ) d1
  )
SELECT
  di1.row_number
FROM data_index di1
WHERE di1.id = 3;
```

Then use position to offset the dataset.

All together:

```
WITH
  data_index AS (
    SELECT
      d1.*,
      row_number() OVER () row_number
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id
      FROM probe
      ORDER BY description ASC
    ) d1
  ) 
SELECT
  di1.id
FROM data_index di1
WHERE di1.row_number > (
  SELECT
    di1.row_number
  FROM data_index di1
  WHERE di1.id = 3
)
LIMIT 10;
```

The downside of this approach is that `data_index` needs to load the entire sub-query into memory. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Error in the question. Correct. IDs are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply add the column used for the ordering (`description`) to the `SELECT` list and the `WHERE` clause of the following queries:

```
-- 1st query:
SELECT
  id, description
FROM probe
ORDER BY description, id
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Lets say that you get `@id = 3` and `@description = 'Beta'` as the last (5th) row. You can then use these values to get the next (5) rows:

```
-- next query:
SELECT
  id, description
FROM probe
WHERE (description, id) > (@description, @id)
ORDER BY description, id
LIMIT 5 ;
```

Comment: For those not familiar with the syntax used in this answer, refer to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON.

Answer (score 0):

If you order the result by `description` then you have to fetch the next portion by `description` not by `id` that is unrelated to the order.